# I18n of submit in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have trying to add internationalization to my Rails app. I've read rails guides and all parts of app was internationalized successfully except Submit button. Actually I've translated it partially.
Looked at source code of `submit` method, I've read commentary before declaration of the method.
There is part from that commentary:

```
 en:
   helpers:
     submit:
       create: "Create a %{model}"
       update: "Confirm changes to %{model}"
```

I've used that example in my `config/locales/??.yml` files. And have a trouble to translate `%{model}`. Name of my Model always in english.

How can I translate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can translate specific model names like this, eg for `es.yml`:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      my_model_name: new_model_name
```